# Need help to know how to use threads while reading a single directory

Tags: c, multithreading

I need to read a single directory containing 100K files. Every time when i do readdir this is taking lot of time.

Can someone suggest me the logic of how to read a single directory using multiple threads. Consider this directory is not having any sub-dir, only files.

Below is what i am trying to make it work but this is taking ~5 min per invocation

```
 void dirwalk(char *dir, void (*fcn)(char *))
   {
   char name[MAX_PATH];
   Dirent *dp;
   DIR *dfd;

   if ((dfd = opendir(dir)) == NULL) {
       fprintf(stderr, "dirwalk: can't open %s\n", dir);
       return;
   }
   while ((dp = readdir(dfd)) != NULL) {
       if (strcmp(dp->name, ".") == 0
           || strcmp(dp->name, ".."))
           continue;    /* skip self and parent */
       if (strlen(dir)+strlen(dp->name)+2 > sizeof(name))
           fprintf(stderr, "dirwalk: name %s %s too long\n",
               dir, dp->name);
       else {
           sprintf(name, "%s/%s", dir, dp->name);
           (*fcn)(name);
       }
   }
   closedir(dfd);
  }
```

Comment: How did you figure that multithreading is a solution to that particular problem (Hint: The CPU is probably not your bottleneck when reading a directory)?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "is taking lot of time." How much time? Also, you should edit your question to include some of the code you have written so far.

Comment: As currently written, your question is too broad to answer except with generalities.

Comment: Posting your current code could be a good starting point.

Comment: Any way if threading can help here?

Comment: How much time (in %) is spent for `(*fcn)(name);` ?

Comment: Double `strcmp` can be easily avoided.

Comment: OT: `strlen()` is a performance-killer. At least this `strlen(dir)` can be moved out of the loop.

Comment: `strlen(dir)` can be called once, but probably optimizer already did that for you.

Comment: Also: Does is take as well that long if the code doesn't call `fcn()`?

Comment: `sprintf( "%s/%s", ... )` is also a slow way to concatenate strings.

Comment: Install atop (or something similar) and run `sudo atop` while running this. You will almost certainly see that one of your disks is maxed out on reads.

Comment: @evaitl - has it been established OP is using Linux?

Comment: @ryyker I skipped that step because the code sample smells like linux.

Comment: XY problem. Do you have any indocation, the CPU is not just waiting for IO to finish? When optimising, first make sure you look into the correct direction.

Comment: If that takes five minutes the problem probably lies in `fcn`, as you're skipping everything except `".."`.

Comment: @molbdnilo: lol, nice catch! But probably a copypasta error ...

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. i figured out fcn need some optimization. I'm trying with some benchmarks on other FSes with same code.

Comment: I checked atop and disks latency is alright

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following in the order below to see if it improves the performance:

1. Spawn a different thread using `pthread_create()` primitive to perform the action in `fcn()` to remove any possibility of an expensive operation that could come along with the function callback. Based on your need, you could create joinable or detached threads. If this does not help, try 2 below.
2. Write a modified dirwalk() function as part of a thread routine. Create a bunch of threads (using `pthread_create()` primitive) that call the same thread routine from outside. The threads would run until they reach the end of the directory stream. Remember the directory stream is always shared, and `readdir()` is not a reentrant function. So use `readdir_r()` instead to your advantage. Also use the pthread_mutex to lock the directory stream. Remember to lock and unlock before and after the readdir_r() respectively, so that the rest of the work is done outside the critical section.

Locking would have a bearing on the performance, but it should take care of the concurrency issues and you cant avoid locking. However, I think Linux (I hope you are running Linux) would provide a little more opportunity for the dirwalk() to run with more threads but I am not sure if it would be as substantial as you might expect.

Comment: Thanks for kicking some ideas!
I'm not convinced with modifying dirwalk since this is single directory. Still i'll re-look.

Comment: A simple fact that your code *must* always be reentrant should help you convince that a modified dirwalk() is inevitable.